# ASP.NET WebForms C# if url is same as hyperlink add class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have several links that look like the following:

```
<ul>
    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="lnk1" NavigateUrl="~/section/sub-section/page1" runat="server">My Link</asp:HyperLink></li>
    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="lnk2" NavigateUrl="~/section/sub-section/page2" runat="server">My Link</asp:HyperLink></li>
</ul>
```

What I want to do is in the code-behind is add a class of selected if the link url matches the url of the page that is currently being viewed.

How would I do this? Thanks

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Haven't tried anything as I don't know C# particularly well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your hyperlinks in Panel like this

```
<asp:Panel id="pnl" runat="server">
<ul>
    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="lnk1" NavigateUrl="~/section/sub-section/page1" runat="server">My Link</asp:HyperLink></li>
    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="lnk2" NavigateUrl="~/section/sub-section/page2" runat="server">My Link</asp:HyperLink></li>
</ul>
</asp:Panel>
```

Then in your code behind iterate through each HyperLink control:

```
foreach (Control lnk in pnl.Controls)
        {
            if (lnk is HyperLink)
            {
                HyperLink href = (HyperLink)lnk;
                if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Equals(href.NavigateUrl))                
                    href.Attributes.Add("class", "selected");                
            }
        }
```

Hope this will help..

Comment: I have more than one link so passing the ID across for each one isn't ideal... How could I do it for a list of links?

Comment: Either place all your link in PlaceHolder or Panel and then iterate through Child controls: 
        foreach (Control lnk in p.Controls) //p is id of panel
        {
            if (lnk is LinkButton)
            {
                LinkButton lbtn = (LinkButton)lnk;
                if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Equals(lbtn.NavigateUrl))                
                    lbtn.Attributes.Add("class", "selected");                
            }
        }

Comment: Can you show an example of this? What I would have the page and what I would have in the code behind. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

in the Page.Request object you do have properties to get the RawUrl of the current page, doing a loop in the Page.Controls you could find all your hyper links, you can then compare the NavigateUrl attributes with the page url and you are set.

Keep in mind that if you want to change an attribute of the server controls from code behind you better do it only in the `Page_PreRender` method because if you it before your changes could be overwritten...

Answer (score 0):

You can get current file name on Master page

```
string currentpage = Request.FilePath;
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be something like (you'll need to tweek the `equality` comparison):

```
if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri == lnk1.NavigateUrl) { lnk1.Attributes.Add("class", "selected"); }
```

Comment: I have more than one link so passing the ID across for each one isn't ideal... How could I do it for a list of links?

Comment: I see - then I'd recommend `foreach` all your pages controls for type `HyperLink`.